# iterm2 excute "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" before init a shell profile every time

Tags: terminal, zsh, init, profile, iterm2

As this image show, I just create new tab, it will excute "export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" thrice times. my profile only excute "zsh" command when the profile init.

[image]
[image]

[image]
"Terminal" app not have this print with zsh. so it must be iterm2 problem.

And I have checked .zshrc and .bash_profile, not have this command neither.